# Anti-log of a number

Tags: logarithms

If we accept both positive and negative values for the square root of a number, then can the anti-log of a number be negative?

Comment: It can be negative if you consider the complex field like you do with square root of a negative number.

Comment: But the square root of a negative number is not a real number whereas anti-log gives us real values.

Comment: You are allowed to use the traditional name, "exponential function". The exponential function has only positive values over the reals.

Comment: And please define what you think the logarithm is, from most of the motivations, historical and recent, it is clear that the (real-valued) logarithm is only defined for positive numbers.

Comment: A logarithm is actually the power to which the base needs to be raised to get a particular number.

Comment: I've read in some other threads that we always take positive values for square root. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

> *can the anti-log of a number be negative?*

If by “anti-log” you mean the [exponential function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function), then we have [Euler's famous identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity) $e^{i\pi}=-1$

Comment: By anti-log I mean what we find in anti-log tables. I don't know if its called exponential function.

Comment: So basically $\log x=a$, where *a* is known, and *x* is the unknown ? In this case, you simply apply the fact that $\log\dfrac1x=-\log x=-a$.

Comment: I get what you have written. But what I meant by my question was that suppose you have a number $x$ such that $log x $ = $a$. Now, to find out the square root of $x$, we multiply $a$ by 1/2 and find the anti log of the obtained number. But as we know the square root of $x$ can be negative or positive , then shouldn't we also have negative value for anti-log?

Comment: Not negative, but complex, since $\log\Big(-\sqrt x\Big)=\log\Big((-1)\cdot\sqrt x\Big)=\log\Big(-1\Big)+\log\Big(\sqrt x\Big)=$ $=\log e^{(2k+1)\pi i}+\dfrac12\log x=\dfrac a2+(2k+1)\pi i$.

Comment: But we still have to find $antilog (\dfrac{a}{2}) + antilog (2k+1)\pi i$ to get the answer and how do we find that?

Comment: $e^{x+y}\neq e^x+e^y$. Rather, $e^{x+y}=e^x\cdot e^y$. The number you're looking for is $-\sqrt{e^a}$.

Comment: Ok. So, the it's $antilog [\dfrac a2+(2k+1)\pi i]$, right?

Comment: Yes. $\log\Big(-\sqrt{e^a}\Big)=\dfrac a2+(2k+1)\pi i$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But we don't use negative values for anti-logs in calculations.  Why is that?

Comment: Sorry, I've just realized that I hadn't understood your question. You were talking about the case $\log_xa=b$, and what I had in mind was $\log_ax=b$. In which case the answer is simple: because a function can only have one value in any given point. Just like in the case of square roots, when we choose only the positive value from among the two possible results. $\sqrt9=3$, not $-3$, and $\log_x9=2$ returns only $x=3$, not $x=-3$. After all, it is a bit redundant to mention both, isn't it ?

Comment: But in some cases it may be non-trivial to mention both. Think about it.

Comment: Do you have something specific in mind ?